# Java issue, java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I'm trying to read line by line from an RSS feed.

And I keep getting this error;

java.io.FileNotFoundException: (name of location of Android App)

Since its being read, from the RSS feed and actually outputs some of the xml I don't see where there could be an error. Anyone ever run into this problem?

```
        URL url = new URL(urlText);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine=in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            count++;
            try{
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder= dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputLine);
               doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            }

        }
```

Comment: Which line is the exception coming from?

Comment: Which line provoke the error?

Comment: Can you post the logcat and show us the line where you get the error?

Comment: What's the value of `urlText`? Does it point to a file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are behind a proxy that is why you are getting issue with url.openStream(). Try to set the proxy configuration, hope it works.

```
String proxyUser = "";
String proxyPassword = "";
String proxyAddress = "";
int proxyPort = 8080;
InetSocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress(proxyAddress, proxyPort);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, sa);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(proxy);
```